# How to count_values() for greater than column counts

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to determine how many rows have over 1000 counts for a specific column within my data.

```
police_2013 = pd.read_csv('..Data.csv')
police_2013.unit.value_counts()
```

In this code, `police_2013.unit.value_counts()` gives me how many calls the Unit had. I want to count up the units that had the previous formula where the result was over 1000.

This failed:

```
countif(police_2013.unit.value_counts() > 1000)
unit_count_1000 = len(police_2013[police_2013['unit'] > 1000])
```

Comment: Please add example data so we can answer your question better.

Comment: Please add not only sample data but also an example of what result you are looking for. This will help us answer your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this.
This gives you how many unique values > 1000 are in the column `unit` of your dataset

```
len(police_2013[police_2013['unit']>1000].unit.value_counts())
```